# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, typeerror

```
p=range(0,1200,10)
lenp=len(p)
rp=1.331
po=1000
T=280
Temp=(lenp)

for i in p:
    Temp[i]=T*(p[i]/po)**rp
print T
```

Im getting this error and don't know how to fix it...

```
Temp[i]=T*(p[i]/po)**rp

TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 5):

You are presumably trying to build a list of length `lenp` here. You'd need to create a list by multiplication here:

```
Temp = [None] * lenp
```

but you'd be better off building the list by appending to it:

```
Temp = []
for i in p:
    Temp.append(T * (i / po) ** rp)
```

where you don't use `p[i]` but `i` *directly*; Python `for` loops are *for each* loops really.

Your `range()` produces values in the series `[0, 10, 20, ... 1200)` and the `for` loop assigns each of those values to `i` per iteration. If you use `i` to index into `p` again you'd run into problems; `p[0]` would still be `0`, but `p[10]` would then be `100`, `p[20]` is `200`, etc. until `p[120]` throws an `IndexError` because there are only 119 different values in that range.

You can collapse the `for` loop appending to `Temp` into a list comprehension to build the list in one go:

```
rp=1.331
po=1000
T=280

Temp = [T * (i / po) ** rp for i in range(0, 1200, 10)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues in your code.

The most immediate one is that your `Temp` value is not a sequence that you can assign things to, just an integer (the parentheses don't do anything). While you could make it into a tuple by adding a comma, that still won't let you assign values into `Temp` after it has been created (tuples are immutable). Instead, you probably want a list.

However, there's another issue with your loop. A for loop like `for value in sequence` assigns values from the `sequence` to the variable `value`. It doesn't assign indexes! If you need indexes, you can either use `enumerate` or use a different looping construct, such as a list comprehension.

Here's a minimally changed version of your code that first creates a list of `lenp` zeros, then replaces their values with the computed ones:

```
p=range(0,1200,10)
lenp=len(p)
rp=1.331
po=1000
T=280
Temp=[0]*lenp

for i, p_value in enumerate(p):
    Temp[i]=T*(p_value/po)**rp
print T
```

Here's a more pythonic version that uses a list comprehension instead of an ordinary loop:

```
rp=1.331
po=1000
T=280
Temp = [T*(p_value/po)**rp for p_value in range(0,1200,10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Temp` is not a tuple, it's just an integer in parenthesis. You can fix this with a simple `,`. Consider the following:

```
>>> x = (42)  # not a tuple
>>> x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> 
>>> x = (42,)  # tuple
>>> x[0]
42
```

**However**, tuples are immutable, and you cannot perform such an assignment:

```
>>> x[0] = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

You can fix this issue by using a list instead.

Comment: But the OP is trying to **assign** to indices; a tuple won't allow that.

Comment: By adding the comma the OP can *index* into `x`, but still won't be able to modify it, for two reasons: (1) tuples are immutable.  (2) `i` is looping over values which aren't really tuple or array indices.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that's a good point. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that when we assign a (number) to x, this is what is actually happening,

```
>>> x = (50)
>>> x
50
```

So if you want to create an empty list , you can do it this way

```
rows = 5
cols = 3
matrix = [[0 for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
```

Its gonna create something like this one,

```
>>> matrix
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```